# AccessViolationException and Faulting module: What is causing this exception? Is it the faulting module?

Tags: wcf, com, vb6, access-violation, sta

If an AccessViolationException occurs, does the faulting module related to it mean that it's a bug in that module, which in our case happens to be one of our third-party DLLs? Or is this much more complicated problem? We have contacted the makers of this module but they haven't found any bug, just suggesting possible stack corruption what ever that means. However, according to the event log a particular faulting module is always associated with the AccessViolationException. So what's truth about this? Is it a buggy third-party DLL module or something else?

Background

We're using a mutex-protected VB6 STA COM object in a .NET WCF web service running on IIS 7. Lately we have detected random System.AccessViolationException errors (caused by this object) crashing the web service completely and we're pretty helpless at the moment as we've done everything to make this COM object work with the web service. The service itself has been set to run in STA mode using the following guide: (http://scottseely.com/2009/07/17/calling-an-sta-com-object-from-a-wcf-operation/

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the full exception please?

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly related to VB6 run-time leaking upon thread termination. VB6 ActiveX DLL projects have options for "Unattended execution" and "Retain in memory" that try to mitigate these issues by keeping the run-time on a STA thread as long as possible. Ask your vendor if these options are applicable to their component.

In either case best would be to keep those STA threads from terminating, implementing a pool of them (or serializing on a single STA thread), so that VB6 run-time does not try to tear-down it's internal structures at any time (and leak handles/memory/TLS doing it).

Search for using VB6 components under COM+/MTS, might find valuable advice. And best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for advice. Would it make any difference if we used a static COM object? Currently we're always creating a new instance of the COM component (protected by a mutex). I've read that static variables are not removed during thread termination and it only becomes a matter with IIS recycling.

Comment: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Sep/18/Creating-STA-COM-compatible-ASPNET-Applications